# wpf 3D object StoryBoard Animation point XYZ in code

Tags: wpf, object, animation, 3d, point

1. I want to change 3D object point XYZ.
2. Is it possible ?
3. have you any reference? many reference tools have not Point3D Animation
4. how to use Point3D Property?

I want to make that : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTz7jSU-C5I

## Animation

```
Storyboard s = new Storyboard();

        ModelVisual3D MV = mainViewport.Children.ElementAt(current) as ModelVisual3D;
        Model3DGroup cube = MV.Content as Model3DGroup;

        for (int j = 0; j < cube.Children.Count; j++)
        {

            Model3DGroup Point_X= cube.Children[j] as Model3DGroup;

            DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            doubleAnimation.To = 2;
            doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            s.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
            s.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, cube);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(" ??? "));

            s.Begin(); // Exception during the execution.

        }
```

Comment: such animation are generally applied on transforms. we would be able to provide you an example once you decide what animation you want the cube to perform i.e. move, rotate, re-size etc.

Comment: I want to move point3D XYZ, have you any example in code?